# Match all nodes that contain a child node with specific contents

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Suppose I this have this XML doc, where ... just represents other miscellaneous nodes:

```
<AA>
    <BB>
        <CC>True</CC>
        ...
    </BB>

    <BB>
        <CC>True</CC>
        ...
    </BB>

    <BB>
        <CC>False</CC>
        ...
    </BB>

    <BB>
        <CC>True</CC>
        ...
    </BB>


    <BB>
        <CC>False</CC>
        ...
    </BB>
</AA>
```

I'm trying to make some templates, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="/">

<DD>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/AA/YYY" />
</DD>

<EE>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/AA/XXX" />
</EE>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="YYY">
 <!-- do stuff -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="XXX">
   <!-- do stuff -->
</xsl:template>
```

To produce output similar to this:

```
<AA>
    <DD>
        <BB>
            <CC>True</CC>
        </BB>
        <BB>
            <CC>True</CC>
            ...
        </BB>

        <BB>
            <CC>True</CC>
            ...
        </BB>
    </DD>

    <EE>
        <BB>
            <CC>False</CC>
            ...
        </BB>

        <BB>
            <CC>False</CC>
            ...
        </BB>
    </EE>
</AA>
```

I am just struggling to find xpaths to place in the match attributes, where I currently place XXX and YYY.  Anyone got the answer?

Basically I want to select all nodes that have a child node that contains a specific contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an identity transform, you shouldn't need any additional templates if you're not going to change anything in the `<BB>` elements.

**XML Input**

```
<AA>
  <BB>
    <CC>True</CC>
    ...
  </BB>

  <BB>
    <CC>True</CC>
    ...
  </BB>

  <BB>
    <CC>False</CC>
    ...
  </BB>

  <BB>
    <CC>True</CC>
    ...
  </BB>


  <BB>
    <CC>False</CC>
    ...
  </BB>
</AA>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/AA">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <DD>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="BB[CC='True']"/>
      </DD>
      <EE>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="BB[CC='False']"/>
      </EE>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<AA>
  <DD>
    <BB>
      <CC>True</CC>
      ...
    </BB>
    <BB>
      <CC>True</CC>
      ...
    </BB>
    <BB>
      <CC>True</CC>
      ...
    </BB>
  </DD>
  <EE>
    <BB>
      <CC>False</CC>
      ...
    </BB>
    <BB>
      <CC>False</CC>
      ...
    </BB>
  </EE>
</AA>
```

If you do need to change `<BB>` add additional template(s) to override the identity transform.

Comment: Thanks.  The `BB[CC='True']` syntax was what I was looking for.  I needed to do more than the original question suggested, it was just this one piece was majorly hanging me up.  Thanks for the clear answer and good example input/outputs.